# Is Castle ActiveRecord compatible with .NET 3.5 and up?

Tags: asp.net, .net, activerecord

We currently use ActiveRecord in combination with a web application build on asp.NET 2.0.

When upgrading to .NET version 3.5 or 4.0 and up, it gives a lot of conflicts with regard to ActiveRecord. It seems to be incompatible with more recent .NET frameworks. Is this really the case or does someone have good experiences with it?
If yes, any sources would be highly appreciated!